# Definição e utilidade de partial class

Tags: c#

Qual é a utilidade de uma `partial class`, e em que situações é recomendado utiliza-las? Tenho algumas classes em um projeto que são `partial classes` e suspeito que um suposto problema está relacionado a isto.

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Com certeza, não é o partial class que irá gerar problemas, é uma notação para a mesma classe ficar em arquivos diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes parciais são geralmente usadas com códigos gerados por alguma ferramenta, de forma a permitir que o programador injete código dentro dessa classe gerada, sem ter de alterar o arquivo de código gerado.

Fora essa utilidade, eu diria que usar classes parciais em um código não gerado, faz o código ficar confuso. Alguns já tentaram me convencer de que isso poderia ser usado para organizar melhor as funções de uma classe, mas existem padrões de codificação para isso.

O princípio [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) por exemplo, proíbe uma mesma classe de ter diversas funções... dessa forma, não seria necessário ter de separar o código de uma mesma classe em várias partes por conta de organização.

Answer (score 2):

Embora frequentemente referidas como classes parciais (ou tipos parciais), trata-se na verdade de uma definição parcial que se rege pela seção §10.2 da especificação.

É geralmente usada por código gerado e permite ao desenvolvedor acrescentar ou modificar, em conjunção com métodos parciais (seção §10.2.7 da especificação), o tipo gerado.

Também é muito útil, por exemplo, para separar a implementação de um tipo em vários ficheiros.

Por exemplo, se for necessário implementar a interaface `IListz<T>` numa classe isso implica implementar um número de interfaces que `IList<T>` extende. Ao colocar a implementação de cada interface no seu próprio ficheiro de definição parcial reduz a dimensão de cada ficheiro tornando mais fácil a sua manutenção. Quando se analiza o histórico do controlo de versões fica também mais fácil ver que parte da classe foi modificada.