# Xamarin Forms - Error CS1061

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-forms

Como resolver o erro **CS1061** no código abaixo:
Código para abrir uma webview local em cada plataforma Xamarin.Forms

```
public partial class MapViewDetail : ContentPage
{
    public interface IBaseUrl   { string Get(); }

    public MapViewDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource();

        string url = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().BaseUrl(); 

        string TempUrl = Path.Combine(url, "mapas.html");
        urlSource.Url = TempUrl;
        Browser.Source = urlSource;
    }
}


[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace AppFrete.UWP
{
    public class BaseUrl : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ms-appx-web:///";
        }
    }
}
```

Erro Apresentado

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl' does not contain a definition for 'BaseUrl' and no extension method 'BaseUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) AppFrete    C:\Users\vinic\source\repos\AppFrete\MapaMVC\AppFrete\AppFrete\View\Map\MapViewDetail.xaml.cs   28  Active

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR;

Esse erro de compilação já te mostra onde e qual é o problema.

> 'MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl' does not contain a definition for 'BaseUrl' and no extension method 'BaseUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl' could be found

(Tradução e destaques meus)

> 'MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl' **não possui uma definição** para `'BaseUrl'` e **nenhum método de extensão** chamado `BaseUrl` aceitando como primeiro argumento um `MapViewDetail.IBaseUrl` foi encontrado

Você está tentando no objeto do tipo `IBaseUrl` consumir um método que não existe (`BaseUrl`).

## Complemento

Eu não sei dizer exatamente qual a sua intenção com o código que foi escrito, ele não faz muito sentido. Deixe-me comentá-lo ao bom e velho *estilo jack*:

#### 1 - Você criou uma classe `MapViewDetail` que herda de `ContentPage`:

```
public partial class MapViewDetail : ContentPage
```

#### 2 - *Dentro* dela você criou uma *Interface* `IBaseUrl` que possui um método `Get` que deve retornar uma string:

```
public interface IBaseUrl   { string Get(); }
```

#### 3 - Voltando ao contrutor da classe `MapViewDetail` é que o erro acontece:

```
// Intancia um objeto qualquer
var urlSource = new UrlWebViewSource(); 

// Tenta recuperar uma instância que implementa IBaseUrl (em outras palavras, 
// a única coisa que você sabe sobre essa instância é que será possível invocar o 
// método Get que te retornaria uma string)
string url = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().BaseUrl();
```

Teóricamente, `DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>()` já te retorna uma instância que implementa a interface queu você declarou, o que **não deve dar erro (mas duvido muito que funcione)** seria `DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();`, que é uma chamada ao método que você declarou na interface.

No entanto, dado [suas perguntas anteriores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/108260/vinicius-dantas?tab=questions) e a quantidade de problemas conceituais que essa pequena parte do código mostra, estou presumindo que você ainda não conhece muito bem a linguagem e o ambiente de desenvolvimento .Net. Se esse for o caso, está começando por um caminho bastante complicado, pois esse pedacinho de código (assim como o próprio `Xamarin`) já utiliza recursos como [Interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107527/78713), [Injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20770/o-que-%C3%A9-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia), [Herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113797/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-heran%C3%A7a) e [Classes parciais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10669/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-utilidade-de-partial-class) que requer que você conheça alguns [pilares da orientação a objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215679/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-pilares-da-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-%C3%A0-objetos).

Só então é que poderemos ajudar dando respostas objetivas. Até lá, eu sugiro que você continue consumindo o conteúdo sobre o assunto aqui mesmo no StackOverflow em Português e que parta de implementações mais simples, como as referências sugeridas na própria [wiki da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Espero ter ajudado.